# OnClientClick causes webpage refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET button on a webpage:

```
<asp:Button ID="TickButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="SelectSome()"  Text="Tick" />
```

and a JavaScript function:

```
 function SelectSome() {
        var id = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSelectSome").value;
        if (isNaN(id)==false)
        {
            var frm = document.forms[0], j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
                if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox" && j < id) {
                    frm.elements[i].checked = true;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You must enter a number.")
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I click on the button; the JavaScript function runs and then the webpage refreshes.  Why does the webpage refresh? According to this link; returning FALSE should stop the webpage from refreshing: [Stop page reload of an ASP.NET button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372431/stop-page-reload-of-an-asp-net-button)

Comment: In referred post there is return on OnClientClick but not in your post, putting that will stop postback. Also use ClientID instead of hardcoding the clientID,  document.getElementById("<%= txtSelectSome.ClientID %>")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `return` for clientclick.

```
<asp:Button ID="TickButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return SelectSome()"  Text="Tick" />
```

OR
you can simply use html button of server side coding is not required then.

```
<asp:Button Text="Tick" runat="server" OnClientClick="return SelectSome()" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will mark this as answered when it lets me.